# Way to accomplish task using list comphrehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a way to accomplish the following using a `list comprehension`?  Or is there a more Pythonic way of accomplishing this?

```
count = 0
x = 'uewoiquewqoiuinkcnsjk'
for letter in x:
    if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        count += 1
```

Just trying to learn the best programming practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `in` generates a `True` or `False` and `True` and `False` [can reliably be used](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) as  `1` and `0` you can use `sum` with a generator:

```
sum(c in 'aeiou' for c in x)
```

Or filter + len:

```
len(filter(lambda c: c in 'aeiou', x))
```

A great way to do the *opposite* is to use str.translate to delete characters in the string:

```
>>> x.translate(None, 'aeiou')
wqwqnkcnsjk
```

So then you can do:

```
len(x)-len(x.translate(None, 'aeiou'))
```

In all cases, the answer is `10`

Comment: `sum` is nice because it doesn't make a list

Answer (score 4):

Use the combination of list_comprehension and len function.

```
>>> x = 'uewoiquewqoiuinkcnsjk'
>>> len([i for i in x if i in 'aeiou'])
10
>>>
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect! Thank you